# Motion Sensor Pop up (dialog) disabled but 3d objects don't move anymore

Tags: javascript, aframe

PROJECT

I have a question regarding a project that I worked on A-Frame Framework with multiple objects(.glb) from the website and to give the objects a fixed position, I used the functionalities of the motion sensor.

PROBLEM

I wanted to disable the pop up notification from the framework and the problem is that the framework does not react to the motion sensor, when I disable the pop-up notification from the framework. What I did is to grant permission manually to the motion sensor with a push of a button and then the notification form iPhone appears and after accepting the permission dialog, the objects stopped moving and does react to the motion sensor. Through debugging it, I saw that the motion sensors were granted permission but the framework does not react to it.

```
<a-scene embedded vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
     device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false">
```

```
function ClickRequestDeviceMotionEvent () {
  window.DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
    .then(response => {
      if (response === 'granted') {
        window.addEventListener('devicemotion',
          () => { console.log('DeviceMotion permissions granted.') },
          (e) => { throw e }
      )} else {
        console.log('DeviceMotion permissions not granted.')
      }
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.error(e)
    })
}
                document.getElementById("splaschreen").addEventListener('click', function () {
                    ClickRequestDeviceMotionEvent()
}
```

What I want is the user to be able to view the website without a popup notification but the motion sensor should work with a click of a button and the objects should remain at the same place in the room.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Share full runnable example to reproduce with https://glitch.com/~aframe or otherwise it will be hard to help.

Comment: Hello thank you for response i did it on glitch, one with the dialog that I dont want but the objects works [with dialog from aframe](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/elite-cuboid-cauliflower) and one like I want to do but the object dont work[with one button press permission grant for motion sensor](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/surf-decorous-sodium)